# Showing list inside list inside list in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have list of "Register" objects.
each Register have list of "Fields".
each Field have list of Bits.

for each register I need to show it's name, its fields name, and its fields bits list.

I tried to do it with ListView inside ListView inside Listiew. It worked, but when more then 20 registers it becomes very slow and can't use this.

Then I tried to use DataGrid but I can't seem to change the values inside. All other solution I found are too complicated.

The classes are:

```
public class FieldBit
{
    public bool _bitValue;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ((_bitValue) ? 1 : 0).ToString();
    }
}

public class Field
{
    public string name;
    public ObservableCollection<FieldBit> bitsList;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Register
{
    public string name;

    public ObservableCollection<Field> reg_fields = new ObservableCollection<Field>();

}
```

The ListView approach:

```
<ListView x:Name="RegistersListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind registersList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="structures:Register">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}" Grid.Row="0" />

                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                            <ListView x:Name="FieldsListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind reg_fields}">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="structures:Field">
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
                                            <ListView x:Name="BitsListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind bitsList}" >
                                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="structures:FieldBit">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind _bitValue}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                            </ListView>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            </ListView>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Here is and example how it should look like:
[image]

Any Ideas for a simple solution that won't stuck my screen?
It's seems that the only solution is DataGrid but i can't seem to build it correctly, any example for triple lists in DataGrid would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to get rid of the `StackPanel`. It's completely unnecessary and disables UI virtualization.

Comment: `TreeView` control seems legit in this case. Try it.

Comment: @mm8 Even it it's help a bit, it probably will not be fast enough, I need different design.

Comment: @Muzib unfortunately target windows version does not support TreeView

Comment: Did you try the [WinUI TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.treeview?view=winui-2.2)

Comment: I tried what you asked but the one that I downloaded making error in my project, may be it's the wrong one, do you know what the exact Nuget name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of trial and error...

- TreeView is not supported in versions earlier than 17134. Even when it is do supported, not all functionality exist as in WPF.
- DataGrid is not the right solution for inner lists.
- The best solution was just to replace ListView with ListBox. ListBox is much better performance then ListView, and have almost no delay.